# What are some alternatives for deferred deep-linking without using the clipboard?

Tags: ios, react-native, clipboard, deep-linking, ios16

Currently we utilize the clipboard for deferred deep linking, but with the upcoming changes to iOS16 we expect the success rate to drop drastically. What other alternative methods are possible? We are considering branch.io but we'd like to explore options for an in-house solution first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

- web app has page, with deep link that is either opens your native app or opens app installation page.
- if native app is installed just use deep link to pass some data
- if native app is not installed, save your data to local storage and continue to app store
- when native app is opened, redirect user to web app, read your local storage and give user some "continue" button, that is actually a deep link, same as on step 1

I wish someone has a better solution.

Comment: Looks promising. Thing is — if the app was installed from the FB app (example:  Facebook ads), then you can't access the same local storage from your app...